# Does Delphi 10 support multi-touch in traditional (non MetroUI) win 32/64 applications?

Tags: delphi, gesture, multi-touch

Does Delphi 10 support multi-touch in traditional (non MetroUI, non-FireMonkey) win 32/64 applications?

I have researched this (and tried it) and it doesn't work.  I would think I should be able to do the following:

1. new Win32 VCL application
2. add a gesture manager to the form
3. assign the gesture manager to the form
4. go into the form's Touch.InteractiveGestures and include igZoom.
5. add a gesture handler event.
6. run the application on a tablet supporting Multi-touch.
7. try a zoom gesture

I would expect the pinch/zoom gesture should fire the event after the gesture has ended event with a code indicating it recognized the zoom event.  Instead, it fires indicating a gesture ID of 0 (unrecognized).

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Where the documentation uses "VCL" it always refers to the Visual Component Library for traditional windows applications (non Metro, non FireMonkey), so yes, gestures are supported.

Comment: gestures, yes.  It would seem multi-touch gestures are not supported on all.

Comment: See the "Interactive Gestures" section - that talks directly about multi-touch gestures for both VCL and FMX.  I guess it depends on what exact type of support you mean - the standard gestures are there (pinch/zoom, two-finger rotate, etc).

Comment: I saw that & yet I haven't seen it work.  Essentially, I would think I should be able to have a new application and do the following:  1. add a gesture manager  2. go into the form's Touch.InteractiveGestures and include igZoom.  3. add a gesture handler event.  4. try the application on a tablet supporting Multi-touch.  The pinch/zoom gesture should fire the event with a code indicating it recognized the zoom event.  Instead, it fires indicating a gesture ID of 0 (unrecognized).

Comment: `OnGesture` will fire continually for any gesture performed, whether it is included in the component's active list or not.  Are you sure you didn't just respond to the first instance of the event (before the system figured out it was a zoom)?

Comment: If this is the case, then you're asking the wrong question "Is it supported?" Instead, ask "Why isn't this working?" and provide us details of what you tried, what you expect and what you get instead. Then we can help you. "Any other ideas?" is not a question fitted for Stack Overflow.

Comment: (edited the question.)  I tried it and the OnGesture event isn't firing throughout the gesture; it only fires at the end.

Comment: I'm hoping you did your basic work in reading the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Gesturing_Overview), which would include the two video links at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I have reviewed the docs before posting this question but not the videos until now.  I'll need to look more into this since it includes a demo of multi-touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the OnGesture event and recognize the gestures yourself.